# Disable source view in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Can I have access to such browser options like disabling `ContextMenu Items` and disable hot-keys (`Ctrl-U`).How to configure browser that the `View Source` option was disabled?

Comment: Try <body oncontextmenu="return false;">

Comment: No you can't. If a user wants to see your HTML source, they can get at it, no matter what you try to do to prevent it. HTML is sent to the user as plain text, and that is how the browser requires it. It cannot be hidden from the user. If you don't want the user to see your front-end code, then the web is the wrong platform for you.

Comment: I'm viewing a web page in chrome (chromium) right now, where "view source" is disabled, and ctrl-u doesn't work to view the source either. So apparently it _is_ possible. Came across this question looking for a way to re-enable view-source and see the underlying html.

Comment: For Future Visitors: Chrome will disable "view source" where the page is not presented as a textual content type (for example, image/jpeg). Check the `content-type` header in chrome dev tools' Network > Docs

Answer (score 0):

There are many solution available to disable context menu using standard JavaScript but I don't think it is possible to disable it using chrome extension.

However to can add or remove custom items to it: More information available here: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus.html

Same goes for shortcuts, I don't think it allows you to overwrite the default behaviour that comes out of box.